# Disable arrow keys in Richtextbox for Another Sub

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox

I wrote a `sub` for execution when the arrow keys are pressed in a Richtextbox. When the arrow keys are pressed it sends to caret up or down after the `Sub` has been executed. How do i overwrite it such that there will be no caret movement but only the execution of the `Sub`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.keyeventargs.handled?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Thanks, I got it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of the newbies, this handled the pressing

`e.Handled = true`